# OpenGL ES 2.0 drawing a texture to the screen wont work

Tags: c++, opengl-es-2.0

I have a program that shall only display a texture to the screen (I am learning OpenGL ES 2.0 right now). I have these shaders:

```
static const char * vertex =
"attribute vec4 position;"
"attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;"
""
"varying vec2 textureCoordinate;"
""
"void main()"
"{"
"    gl_Position = position;"
"    textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;"
"}"
"";

static const char * fragment =
"varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;"
""
"uniform sampler2D videoFrame;"
""
"void main()"
"{"
"    gl_FragColor = texture2D(videoFrame, textureCoordinate);"
"}"
"";
```

They compile fine which is ensured by runtime checks. This code gets the attributes and the sampler:

```
TextureID = glGetUniformLocation(program_id, "videoFrame");
pos = glGetAttribLocation(program_id, "position");
input = glGetAttribLocation(program_id, "inputTextureCoordinate");
```

And this code is used to display my loaded texture:

```
   static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,


  };
static const GLfloat textureVertices[] = {
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
};
glUseProgram(program_id);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);

glVertexAttribPointer(input, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(pos, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureVertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

But the screen stays blank. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: `glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos)` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray(input)` rather than `glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)`. `squareVertices` and `textureVertices` are swapped in `glVertexAttribPointer`.

Comment: What happens if you do `gl_FragColor = texture2D(videoFrame, textureCoordinate) + 0.5;`?

Comment: @Rabbid76 thanks, overseen this! Also +0.5 changes nothing.

Comment: `+ 0.5` does not generate a gray rectangle? Is the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) enabled? If yes, do you clear the depth buffer?

Comment: Try `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)` after generating the texture object (`glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex)`).

Comment: No success unfortunately

Comment: Depth Test is not enabled.

Comment: As it stands there is some important information missing -- OpenGL/toolkit initialization as well as the context in which the various code snippets are used etc.  Can you edit your question to provide a [mcve] that others can use to try and reproduce the problem?

Comment: Okay, ive compiled this on my linux machine now and it works. It seems to be an issue with the Raspberry Pi. Any Idea on that?

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on these lines.

```
glVertexAttribPointer(input, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

Your code previously assigned 'input' to the texture coordinate attribute but here passes the position data. You should also pass the 'pos' attribute to glEnableVertexAttribArray.

```
glVertexAttribPointer(pos, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos);
glVertexAttribPointer(input, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureVertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(input);
```

Since you're passing only two components you may also want to reflect that in your shader by using vec2 rather than vec4.

edit: OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't use layout qualifiers, my mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is definitivley an oversight by me, but the texture still does not show up :/

Comment: Ah sorry. Looks like you're correct Rabbid76. GLES 2.0 does not use layout qualifiers.

Comment: Nidhoegger, if you assign some value to gl_FragColor after the texture2D line, for example `gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);`, do you see anything?

Comment: That weirds out everything for some reason. positition for input cannot be found anymore and the TextureID seems like a random number.

Comment: But no, it does not change anything.

Comment: In hindsight, if you do this the compiler will see the texture2D line as redundant and won't assign the attribute or sampler uniform so glGetAttribLocation will fail. How about modifying the line to something like `gl_FragColor = texture2D(videoFrame, textureCoordinate) + vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);`? This is a bit of a hacky way to debug I admit.